# cp -R No such file or directory

Tags: macos, cp

Why is this failing (on OS X)?

```
$ cp -R dir1 dir2
... # List of all the files in dir1 prefixed with "dir2"
cp: dir2/g: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/h: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/i: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/j: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/k: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/l: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/m: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/n: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/o: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/p: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/q: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/r: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/s: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/t: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/u: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/v: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/w: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/x: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/y: No such file or directory
cp: dir2/z: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause for this is that you don't have permission to create dir2. Look at the beginning of the error output to help diagnose the issue:

```
$ cp -R patient_mgmt_engine lsdkf 2>&1 | head
cp: dir2: Permission denied
...
```

If the issue is that you don't have permission to create dir2, then use `ls -l` to determine which permissions are missing, and `chown` or `chmod` to give yourself permission.